# OAI validation error

Tags: php, xml, oai, oai-pmh

I validated my oai code in openarchives.So many error.Cleared mostly.But still have 2 errors.It shows error like 'FAIL POST test 1 for Identify was unsuccessful, an OAI error response was received'.Anyone know what kind of error is this.Attached [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruYez.png)
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your OAI server does not accept POST requests for these verbs. OAI servers are expected to treat POST and GET requests in the same way.

For instance, these two requests give the same result:

```
curl -d "verb=Identify" http://export.arxiv.org/oai2
curl http://export.arxiv.org/oai2?verb=Identify
```

It should be the same for your server.

Comment: Thank u sir.If now edit my htaccess to enable POST,then it will work sir?

Comment: POST should be enabled indeed. Your PHP script should read its arguments both from $._GET and $._POST.

Comment: Ok sir.Thank you

Comment: Now i added the code to htaccess for enabling POST method.But it shows error like Too many 503 Retry-After or 302 Redirect responses received in a row

Comment: Given the information we have it's hard to tell what is going on - that must be specific to your code or your hosting provider.