# OAI-PMH data provider validation fails for one single POST request, despite it's working with curl

Tags: php, xml, oai, oai-pmh

I'm implementing an OAI-PMH2 compliant data provider in PHP (which retrieves data from a MySQL database), and I'm trying to get it validated, but am stuck with just one error that prevents successful validation.

The error is somewhat related to what is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186043/oai-validation-error), however in my case the POST request with `verb=Identify` passes successfully, while the second one fails.

More annoyingly, the same request is processed successfully when I send it with `curl`, i.e. it outputs a properly formed XML.

To be more specific, the error I get is the following:

```
REQUEST http://www.mydataprovider/my_oaipmh2.php POST 
identifier:oai:www.mydataprovider/my_oaipmh2.php:1 
metadataPrefix:oai_dc verb:GetRecord
FAIL POST test 2 for GetRecord was unsuccessful, got neither a valid response nor an error
```

(www.mydataprovider/my_oaipmh2.php stands for the acual URL, of course.)

So I've tried performing (several times) the same POST request via `curl`, like this:

```
curl --data "verb=GetRecord&metadataPrefix=oai_dc&identifier=oai:www.mydataprovider/my_oaipmh2.php:1" http://www.mydataprovider/my_oaipmh2.php
```

and it always successfully returns a proper XML response with the first record.

What am I missing? Could this be due to some server-side settings?
 
(I don't have access to server management myself, but I could ask the hosting provider, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. The XML resulting from the request wasn't properly formed, since it had a `ListRecords` root element, rather than the appropriate `GetRecord`, i.e. it should have been:

```
<GetRecord>
  <record>
   <header>
   ...
   </header>
  </record>
</GetRecord>
```